# How to jump to different pages or page content using Orchard

Tags: hyperlink, orchardcms

In Orchard 1.6, when editing content, there's a facility to link to external websites/URLs, and indeed how to jump to different anchors on the same page, BUT does anyone know how a user can link to different pages from page content (and also jump to anchors on different pages?

ie a user has created several pages:

page 1
page 2
page 3

and when writing content for page 3, he might want to say something like:

...and  are available here...

and have everything inbetween <...> link to page 2.

Without this ability, Orchard would then simply be a way of constructing disparate/unconnected pages but surely not!?

Thanks in advance.

Sai

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to have dynamically generated links to some content items, right? How about Projector?

Comment: You question doesn't even sound like you want dynamic links, it sounds like you're asking how Orchard can link from one page to another. Is that all you're looking for?

Comment: Hi all, yes, David's correct.  The user is writing some content, and wants to be able to jump to another page.  It's obvious how to do it from HTML, but not via the cms. - in umbraco it's easy as the pages are presented in a list (and before you ask, I decided to go with orchard simply because, in my experience, umbraco fails to save data 100% of the time).

Comment: STOP PRESS! Apparently, this is a missing feature from Orchard :(

Comment: You mean through the body editor? No, I don't think that exists, you'd just need to create a link to a different page

Comment: Believe it or not, almost nobody ever asked for this feature. We do have all the ingredients to make it work however as we have a perfectly good content item picker that could be reused to build this feature.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback chaps, @BertrandLeRoy, yes you're right eg from the navigation option, if you select Content Item then you are presented with a list of current content items from which to choose...   and before you ask, I'm a novice when it comes to "build it yourself" - haven't got a clue about rebuilding :(.